# How can I get suspend or hibernate to work on my Acer Aspire 7551 laptop with Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, hibernate, acer-aspire, suspend

If I try to suspend or hibernate on my Acer Aspire 7551 laptop with Ubuntu 10.04 64bit I can't get it to wake back up.

When I open the lid after suspending I hit a key and see the power button light up but then nothing else happens. FN f2 or FN f4 doesn't help either.

I have to hard power it down in order to get it running again.

I installed with the regular install package and I have a swap partition at /dev/sda5 of 11GB.

For now I set it to go to blank screen when I close the lid but I consider that a temporary solution so I don't lose my work.

Comment: Thanks for the responses Mistiry and Broam. I have some addtional info. I just found that if I suspend and then lift the lid and hit the power button once and then wait for about 5 minutes or so eventually I will see the mouse curser. If I then left click I will be prompted to enter my password and I am back in with my previous windows open.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the X-Server by using Ctrl+Alt+Backspace. It is a known issue with Ubuntu that has been around for years, and this method works to get my screen back.

Not sure what it will do to your running programs; I never leave anything running when I close my laptop so I've never had to find out ;)

[Here's the Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpi/+bug/49521), which goes from June 21, 2006 to September 21, 2010. Told you its been happening for years!

Comment: Caveat: with 10.04 you will need to enable Ctrl-Alt-Backspace as a shortcut to kill the X server.

Comment: Really? Dang...didn't know that. I still run 9.01 on my laptop, 10.04 is my server.

Comment: This bug keeps getting mentioned on every forum someone asks about a 7551 suspend problem, but I have the machine it this is not the solution. It does, in fact, not wake up. Can't ping it, nothing. It is not resuming in any way. I fear the actual problem is being ignored because of this misdiagnoses.